# rgbdslam_v2 not receiving any video stream from Realsense R200

Tags: slam, navigation, realsense, realsense-camera, rgbdslamv2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to use a Realsense R200 camera to generate 3-D maps. For this purpose, I have the realsense_r200_nodelet running on $ROS_MASTER_URI like so

```
roslaunch realsense_camera realsense_r200_nodelet_standalone_manual.launch color_fps:=30 color_height:=480 color_width:=640 depth_fps:=30 depth_height:=480 depth_width:=640
```

I have rgbdslam running on a separate machine. I run it like so

```
roslaunch rgbdslam rgbdslam.launch
```

Unfortunately, I don't see any video being captured on the GUI that comes up. I have updated the rgbdslam.launch file to have the right values for the config parameters. The relevant ones are as shown below

```
<param name="config/topic_image_mono" value="/camera/color/image_raw"/>
<param name="config/topic_image_depth" value="/camera/depth/image_raw"/>
<param name="config/topic_points" value="/camera/depth/points"/>
<param name="config/base_frame_name" value="/camera_link"/>
<param name="config/camera_info_topic" value="/camera/color/camera_info"/>
```

I have confirmed using rviz that my machine does receive video stream from the Realsense camera. Does anyone have any pointers on what I might be doing wrong to not receive anything on the rgbdslam GUI.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/231458/rgbdslam_v2-not-receiving-any-video-stream-from-realsense-r200/) by [archit](https://answers.ros.org/users/26534/archit/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2016-04-08

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [al-dev](https://answers.ros.org/users/18863/al-dev/) on 2016-04-08**:
Did you check that you are receiving both rgb and depth stream ? Are you sure that your rgb topic is `/camera/color/image_raw` ? It seems to me that the default was `/camera/rgb/image_color`.

**Comment by [archit](https://answers.ros.org/users/26534/archit/) on 2016-04-09**:
Yeah, I'm receiving both the rgb and depth streams (checked with rviz). I changed the topic to /camera/color/image_raw because that it is the one on which Realsense sends the rgb stream (it works when used with rviz).

**Comment by [al-dev](https://answers.ros.org/users/18863/al-dev/) on 2016-04-09**:
Ok. Which versions of `rgbdslam` and of the realsense ROS driver are you using ?  I would try setting `config/topic_points` to `""`. As specified in the launch file : "if empty, poincloud will be reconstructed from image and depth"

**Comment by [archit](https://answers.ros.org/users/26534/archit/) on 2016-04-10**:
I'm using `rgbdslamv2` ([repo](https://github.com/felixendres/rgbdslam_v2)) and Intel's package for Realsense ([repo](https://github.com/intel-ros/realsense)). I'm trying what you suggested and it does seem to work. It is just too slow right now.

**Comment by [al-dev](https://answers.ros.org/users/18863/al-dev/) on 2016-04-10**:
The performance can be linked to a number of different factors, you might want to create another ticket for it. If this works I will post it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Set `config/topic_points` to `""`. As specified in the launch file : "if empty, poincloud will be reconstructed from image and depth"

---

Originally posted by [al-dev](https://answers.ros.org/users/18863/al-dev/) with karma: 883 on 2016-04-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0